# find and findindex painful slow for List<Object> why?

Tags: c#, list, find

Im am working in a project that uses intensively List and i try to find the object via the name (that is a member of the object).

My code worked without searching it using a single for-next loop (function find1) but i found that it is possible to the same using the build-in found find, and the code works. However, it feel a bit slow. So, i did a project for test the speed:

I have the next code

```
    public List<MyObject> varbig = new List<MyObject>();
    public Dictionary<string,string> myDictionary=new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        myDictionary.Clear();
        varbig.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            varbig.Add(new MyObject("name" + i.ToString(),"value"+i.ToString()));
            myDictionary.Add("name" + i.ToString(), i.ToString());
        }
        // first test
        var start1 = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
            var ss=find1("name499");
        }
        var end1 = Environment.TickCount;
        Console.WriteLine("time  1 :" + (end1 - start1));
        // second test
        var start2 = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
            var ss=find2("name499");
        }
        var end2 = Environment.TickCount;
        Console.WriteLine("time  2 :" + (end2 - start2));
        // third test
        var start3 = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
            var ss = find3("name499");
        }
        var end3 = Environment.TickCount;
        Console.WriteLine("time  3 :" + (end3 - start3));

        // first test b
        var start1b = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
            var ss=find1("name4999");
        }
        var end1b = Environment.TickCount;
        Console.WriteLine("timeb 1 :" + (end1b - start1b));
        // second test
        var start2b = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
            var ss=find2("name4999");
        }
        var end2b = Environment.TickCount;
        Console.WriteLine("timeb 2 :" + (end2b - start2b));
        // third test
        var start3b = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
            var ss = find3("name4999");
        }
        var end3b = Environment.TickCount;
        Console.WriteLine("timeb 3 :" + (end3b - start3b));

    }

    public int find1(string name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < varbig.Count; i++) {
            if(varbig[i].Name == name) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int find2(string name) {
        int idx = varbig.FindIndex(tmpvar => Name == name);
        return idx;
    }
    public int find3(string name) {
        var ss=myDictionary[name];
        return int.Parse(ss);
    }
}
```

And i use the next object

```
public class MyObject {
    private string _name = "";
    private string _value = "";
    public MyObject() {}

    public MyObject(string name, string value) {
        _name = name;
        _value = value;
    }

    public string Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string Value {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
```

Mostly it do the next thing:
I create an array with 5000 elements.

time 1 = search the 499th object (index) using a simple for-next.

time 2 = search the 499th using the build in function find of List

time 3 = it do the search of the 499th element using dictionary.

Timeb 1, timeb 2 and timeb 3 do the same but try to search the 4999th element instead of the 499th element.

I ran a couple of times :

- time  1 :141
- time  2 :1248
- time  3 :0
- timeb 1 :811
- timeb 2 :1170
- timeb 3 :0
- time  1 :109
- time  2 :1170
- time  3 :0
- timeb 1 :796
- timeb 2 :1170
- timeb 3 :0

*(the small then the fast)*

And, for my surprise, the build in function **findindex** is absurdly slow (in some cases, close to 10x slower. Also, the dictionary approach is almost instantly.

My question is, why?. is it because the predicate?.

Comment: If you're testing timing, use [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) instead of checking `Environment.TickCount`.

Comment: You should consider using a balanced tree if you are doing this type of lookups.

Comment: Another fast approach avoiding a Dictionary is the [Array.BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y15ef976.aspx) which requires to sort your `List<MyObject>` first. Therefore `MyObject` needs to implement `IComparable`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
int idx = varbig.FindIndex(tmpvar => Name == name);
```

`Name == name` is wrong, you should write `tmpvar.Name == name` instead.

In your code you're comparing `name` argument with the `Name`  property of your form; they are obviously different, and so the method always examines the whole list instead of stopping when the searched value is found. In fact, as you can see looking the numbers, the time spent by `find2()` is basically always equal.

About the dictionary, it's obviously faster than the other methods because dictionaries are memory structure specifically built to provide fast keyed access.

In fact they arrive close to `O(1)` time complexity, while looping a list you have a time complexity equal to `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

- Find1 is using a simple for( i = 0 to count) method
- Find2 uses the built in Find method (which is exactly find1 above), except that you have passed a predicate along with it, which I believe is slowing it down.
- Find3 using a dictionary, I would assume is the fastest without any timers, becuase a dictionary uses hashtables under the covers which has an 0(1) look up (contant time)

Answer (score 1):

There is the error in your code - the `find2` method uses the Form.Name for the comparison instead of your collection objects names. It should looks like this:

```
public int find2(string name) {
    return varbig.FindIndex((obj) => obj.Name == name);
}
```

The results without using the Form.Name are more consistent:

```
time  1 :54
time  2 :50
time  3 :0
timeb  1 :438
timeb  2 :506
timeb  3 :0
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put `for` loop to search in `find2`...

Just call `find2` directly, then result will be 0.